# web.config working normally on IIS 10 and returning 403 error on IIS 8.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I was creating rules on IIS 10.0 with URL Rewrite 2.0 like HSTS, XSS Protection...

Everything works fine on IIS 10.0, but when i send the web.config to the IIS 8.5 (with URL Rewrite 2.0 installed) returns 403 invalid credentials.

The old IIS 8.5 web.config was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
       <defaultDocument>
           <files>
               <remove value="index.html" />
               <remove value="Default.asp" />
               <remove value="Default.htm" />
               <remove value="index.htm" />
               <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
               <add value="Attendance.htm" />
           </files>
       </defaultDocument>
       <security>
           <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
               <verbs>
               </verbs>
           </requestFiltering>
       </security>
       <handlers>
           <remove name="CGI-exe" />
           <add name="CGI-exe" path="*.exe" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Execute" allowPathInfo="true" />
       </handlers>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

"requireAccess=Execute"

And the web.config on IIS 10.0 that not worked on IIS 8.5 is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Execute, Script" />
        <security>
            <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true">
                <verbs>
                </verbs>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>           
    <rewrite>     
    <outboundRules>
        <rule name="Add Strict-Transport-Security when HTTPS" enabled="true">
             <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Strict_Transport_Security" pattern=".*" />
             <conditions>
                 <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" ignoreCase="true" />
             </conditions>
             <action type="Rewrite" value="max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" />
         </rule>
        <rule name="Remove Server Header">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_SERVER" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="-" replace="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Remove X-POWERED-BY Header">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X-POWERED-BY" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="-" replace="true"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="RESPONSE_X-ASPNET-VERSION">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X-ASPNET-VERSION" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="-" replace="true" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="RESPONSE_X-ASPNETMVC-VERSION">
            <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_X-ASPNETMVC-VERSION" pattern=".+" />
            <action type="Rewrite" value="-" replace="true" />
        </rule>
         <rule name="Add HttpOnly" preCondition="No HttpOnly">
                     <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
                     <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; HttpOnly" />
                     <conditions>
                     </conditions>
         </rule>
         <rule name="SameSiteCookie">
             <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set-Cookie" pattern="^(.*)(CFID|CFTOKEN|JSESSIONID)(=.*)$" />
             <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0};SameSite=Strict" />
         </rule>
         <preConditions>
             <preCondition name="No HttpOnly">
                 <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
                 <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; HttpOnly" negate="true" />
             </preCondition>
         </preConditions>
      </outboundRules>   
    </rewrite>       
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="X-XSS-Protection" value="1; mode=block" />
            <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
            <add name="Expect-CT" value="max-age=0" />
            <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="sameorigin" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>      
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

"Accesspolicy = read,execute, script"

I was thinking that is something related with the HSTS policy, or the Access Policy have differences between both (one is execute and another read,execute,script). or maybe the URL Rewrite need to disable the Required SSL.
Anyone had any idea?

Comment: Let FRT tell you more about that 403 error, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules

Answer (score 0):

This problem should be related to your IIS version, Before IIS 10.0 version 1709, enabling HSTS on an IIS server requires complex configuration. and the new feature introduced in IIS 10.0 version 1709 is HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS).

More information you can refer to this link: [IIS 10.0 Version 1709 HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS) Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-10-version-1709/iis-10-version-1709-hsts).